# How to determine error code in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

When trying to run a Google Sheet (App Script) that worked in the past I now get this error:
We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code NOT_FOUND. I've copied the Sheet and the copy gets the same error.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducibe example

Comment: Please post [mcve] - [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Server Error is a difficult one.  There is no way to determine the source of the problem from it that I know of.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.